# Meaning of a sentence about law

Tags: meaning, definition

I wanted to know what the last sentence of this paragraph means, what does " know it to be " refer to ?

a person “is not obliged to retreat from his dwelling or place of work, unless he was the initial aggressor or is assailed in his place of work by another person whose place of work the actor knows it to be.”

Comment: Are you studying Law or English?   I ask because if you want to discuss [Law.se] there is a specialist forum.  If you are studying English, you should be aware that legal texts are often written in a style that is unnatural except in legal texts.

Comment: Please quote the sentence starting with the grammatical subject rather than starting it with the verb "is".  I want to make sure I understand properly who "the actor" refers to. It is a case of ellipsis: " ... whose place of work the actor knows it to be [his place of work]."   The referent of the elided pronoun "his" is unclear.

Comment: Also, please cite the source of the quote.